# React js how to return div with async timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, async-await, react-hooks

I'm trying to return a tiny chunk of code in my main return for a component that is timed.  In my return, I want to have the myFunction divs shown after awaiting 5 secs(if the condition is met), but it seems to only display an error. I looked at the react documentation, and it seems you can indeed call a function to return html/jsx, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
Here is my code for this area:

```
function myFunction(){
      return (
        <div className="error-container">
            <h1>Oops!</h1>
            <h2>I ate the page you're looking for</h2>
            <img className="errorImage" src={ErrorImage} alt= 'website error' />
            <Link to='/'><button className="errorButton"> Back to Home </button></Link>
          </div>
      );

    }

    const add5SecondsDelay = () => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(myFunction());
        }, 50000);
      });
    }

    async function asyncFunctionCall() { 
      const result = await add5SecondsDelay ();
    }


  return (
    <div className="detail-container">
        {(() => {
           if(!item.name){
            return (
              <div>
              {asyncFunctionCall()}

              </div>


            )
          } else{
```

I am still new to these sort of things, so I might be messing up my promise or something. I just can't figure out how to make it return my HTML/JSX after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use useEffect hook to wait those 5 seconds and change the state of a variable, then in your return just do something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyDiv = () =>  (<div>Hi</div>)

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isDivVisible , setIsDivVisible ] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsDivVisible(true)
      console.log('5 seconds later')
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return isDivVisible ? <MyDiv/> : <div>Loading</div>
}
```

check this pen: https://codepen.io/ealipio/pen/yLYJvVW?editors=0010

Comment: Hey I added the stuff you have and then put this in the return, however it isn't doing anything or waiting 5 secs. Am I supposed to do something special around the "isDivVisible ?" and " : null " to make it work in my JSX?

Comment: What I have:  return (
              <div>
                isDivVisible ? 
                <div className="error-container">
                  <h1>Oops!</h1>
                  <h2>I ate the page you're looking for</h2>
                  <img className="errorImage" src={ErrorImage} alt= 'website error' />
                  <Link to='/'><button className="errorButton"> Back to Home </button></Link>
                  </div> : null
              </div>
              
            )

Comment: Hi Andrews, I updated the answer including this pen when you can see the code working, also I updated the return replacing the null, I just returned null because do not want to render anything but you can render another component if you wish. hope it helps :)